# Is there any way to find version of boringssl and protobuf we are using in AOSP

Tags: android-source

I have boringssl and protobuf inside/external in AOSP. How do I find the version of boringssl and protobuf we are using in AOSP?

Answer (score 0):

Protobuf: You will find the version in external/protobuf/js/package.json